# Dates matching in 2 different dataframes

Tags: r

I have some financial data. For index 1 I have 1583 observations, for index 2 I have 1598 observations. I have collected data for index 1 up until 2017-06-15 and for index 2 I have data up until 2017-06-09. They both start on the same date.

My question is: how can I compare and locate the missing dates from the two dataframes and remove the dates where the index does not match?

I am trying to achieve two dataframes where the dates for index 2 matches the dataframe for index 1. I am happy to remove some observations when and where the dates are not the same.

Comment: Please add an example of your data

Comment: Use `merge` or `inner_join` from the `dplyr` package.

Answer (score 1):

this example will help you generate dummy data for future reference, the last line is the command that would accomplish what you are seeking.

```
set.seed(1984)  ## to make the data repoducible

#simulating the data 

z1 <-  as.numeric(as.Date('2015-05-01')) + sample(1:100,20)
z2 <-  as.numeric(as.Date('2015-05-01')) + sample(1:100,20)

z1 <- as.Date(z1, origin = '1970-01-01')
z2 <- as.Date(z1, origin = '1970-01-01')

z11 <- sample(1:100,20)
z21 <- sample(1:100,20)


df1 <- data.frame(z1,z11)
df2 <- data.frame(z2,z21)


# the merge 

merge(df1,df2, by.x = 'z1', by.y = 'z2', all = F)
```